# Why te is used when the object and subject aren't same

Tags: gramática

I am new to spanish and iam learning it on duolingo and now I'm stucked I have a questions

question In the sentences "pensamos que te va a gustar" Why te is used when the object and subject aren't same

Comment: Do you know how gustar works? Me gusta, te gusta, le gusta, etc. I like it, you like it, she/he likes it.

Comment: You are to do your own research before asking a question on SE. A good start for you is to read something about _gustar_, for example [this page](https://www.speakeasybcn.com/en/blog/the-spanish-verb-gustar-how-to-use-it-and-other-related-verbs).

Comment: Try thinking of gustar as equivalent to the verb to please in English _me gusta_ = it pleases me = I like it.